# Adapt perl script to run from cgi

Tags: mongodb, perl, shell, cgi

I have a perl script which works fine from shell but doesn't work from web (lighttpd + mod_cgi). I found out that problem is with the following string

```
my $lastupdate = `/opt/mongo/bin/mongo 127.0.0.1:27117/getVersion -u test -p test --eval 'db.polling.find({},{"_id":0,"host":0,"ports":0}).sort({"date":-1}).limit(1).forEach(function(x){printjson(x)})' | awk -F'"' '/date/{print \$4}' |sed 's/T/,/;s/Z//'`;
```

As i understood, when running from cgi, string is not being splitted. So i have done this by my own

```
my $lastupdate = system('/opt/mongo/bin/mongo', '127.0.0.1:27117/getVersion', '-u', 'test', '-p', 'test', '--eval', 'db.polling.find({},{"_id":0,"host":0,"ports":0}).sort({"date":-1}).limit(1).forEach(function(x){printjson(x)})', '|', 'awk', '-F', '"', '/date/{print', '\$4}', '|sed', 's/T/,/;s/Z//');
```

Script works now but gives me unexpected value (differs from shell's run value). 
What did i miss? 
P.S. I know that there are smarter ways to interact mongoDB from perl, but my env is totally firewalled. I have access neither to CPAN, nor to rh repos and  perl mongoDB driver has too much deps to install it manually.

Comment: I think the problem maybe with piping of the output to the awk command.. This [Perlmonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=908096) might point you in the right direction

Comment: You should perform the awk and sed parts in perl.

Comment: You can't capture the output of `system`. You'll want to use [IPC::Open2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html)

Comment: Also, you'll really want to educate yourself about securing your perl CGI scripts. Lots of info on google no doubt, and http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=cgi

Comment: @glenn  
I switched to IPC::Run  
my $testo = IPC::Run::run \@cmd, '|', \@awk - returns bool value  
How can i assign output of run to variable

Comment: Doesn't look like you're calling run with the right args. Check [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

Comment: No, it works and gives me output. I just want to store output in variable, not in stdout. I can redirect output to file and then populate variable from this file, but i suspect there is more simple way.

Answer (score 2):

The environment that you run a program under from a shell is completely different to the environment that the same program gets when run from a web server. Most obviously, it will be run as a different user - one who will have far more restricted filesystem permissions that the average user.

You can (partly) simulate this by working out which user your web server runs as (perhaps apache, www or nobody) and using `sudo` to run your program as that user. This might well reveal what the problem is.

You can't just switch from backticks to `system()`. Backticks return the output from running the command line and `system()` returns a [value which requires some interpretation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). That'll be why you're seeing a different result.